Autofac: How to register dynamically register concrete types with generic with their own interfaces with generic type
AutoFac newbie here! I have a couple of types which take a generic, each with their own interfaces which take the same generic. Eg:
public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
   ...
}

public class Bar<T> : IBar<T>
{
   ...
}

I'm trying to register these with AutoFac, but I can't get them to register and be resolved in a dynamic way.
I thought I'd try just a fairly standard registration, eg:
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
    .Where(x => x.GetConstructors().Any(c => c.IsPublic))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf();

And I can see the registrations if I debug and inspect the container. But if I try to resolve the service, it can't find it:
var x = _container.Resolve<IFoo<MyGenericType>>();

Fair enough, maybe it doesn't know how to resolve it.
I've looked at containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(), but my types don't all inherit from a single generic type interface so I'm not sure how that would solve it?
I can register them manually and it works:
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Foo<>)).As(typeof(IFoo<>));
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Bar<>)).As(typeof(IBar<>));

But is there a way to do this dynamically using AutoFac?

Let's admit IFoo & IBar implement IInjectable interface, by reflexion you can scan assembly to achieve your goal

Yep I can probably do it by adding a marker interface and fetching the types, then registering them. But is there not a built in way to achieve this with AutoFac?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78408302/17838896

Have you seen RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes in the docs?

That worked perfectly @TravisIllig! Thank you! Don't know how I never spotted that - if you post it as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

I posted it as an answer. If you wouldn't mind returning to accept it...? Glad it worked for you!

The answer here is the RegisterAsssemblyOpenGenericTypes method, as outlined here in the documentation.

By reflection and common interface
using System.Reflection;
interface IFoo<T> : IInjectable
{

}

interface IBar<T> : IInjectable
{

}
interface IInjectable
{

}

class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{

}

class Bar<T> : IFoo<T>
{

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(IInjectable).IsAssignableFrom(x));
        foreach (var type in types.Where(t => t.IsClass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

